# Metaphorical use of "the cockpit"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

What is the metaphorical meaning of  *cockpit* in the following sentence?

“The cockpit of this fought was the Senate of the US”
(Profiles in courage by John F. Kennedy)

Comment: ***Cockpit (n.)***: 
1580s, "a pit for fighting cocks," from cock (n.1) + pit (n.1). Used in nautical sense (1706) for midshipmen's compartment below decks; transferred to airplanes (1914) and to cars (1930s). Etymonline

Comment: I checked online to find the exact quote, but came up empty handed. Are you *sure* you cited JFK's words correctly? Please, do not shorten citations or "simplify" them. I might have said "This was fought in the cockpit of the US Senate".

Answer (score 2):

The original meaning of *cockpit* per the OED was:

> A pit or enclosed area in which game-cocks are set to fight for sport;
>   a place constructed for cock-fighting.

Any other use of *cockpit* is in some sense metaphorical of that - in the case of its nautical and aeronautical use, it refers to the cramped space - one supposes.

But in the use you report the sense of a 'fighting space' is retained.

In the decades prior to the first world war, the Balkans was often described as *the cockpit of Europe* because of the confused rivalries and tentative alliances which existed. Ultimately it provided the spark which gave rise to the conflagration.

Answer (score 0):

This use is from cock fighting, which was held in a pit.<sup>[W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockfight)</sup>

> Cockpit - a place where a battle or other conflict takes place.
>   "the cockpit of capitalist conflict in Europe" <sup>[G](https://www.google.com/search?q=cockpit&oq=cockpit&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

"Cockpit" here means the place where the fight was held. '

As per dictionary.com, one of the meanings of this word is

> a place where a contest is fought or which has been the scene of many contests or battles. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cockpit