# What is the etymology of the term "Cockpit"?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution

I have always been intrigued by the word *cockpit* and have wondered where it originated.

I have heard that it originated in the times of cock fights; is this true? If it is, how did the word evolve from having its original cockfighting meaning to being the name for the portion of an airplane or vehicle where the pilot and copilot sit?

Comment: Had you thought about looking it up in an etymology dictionary, or even a lexical one? Because that's all we'll do. Cut out the middleman!

Comment: @BillJ Do you know of any good online sources?

Comment: @ NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ  http://www.etymonline.com/

Comment: Are you asking about the origin of the word itself (which seems rather self-explanatory - a pit (an area reserved or enclosed for a specific activity (ie: cock (a male chicken) - fighting) )),  or how it evolved to be applicable to the portion of the plane where the pilot sits?

Comment: @IanW The evolution of the word to the modern usage for an aircraft cockpit or such.

Comment: Voted to re-open: the brief etymonline.com entry doesn't really answer the question in full.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Metaphorical use of "the cockpit"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272926/metaphorical-use-of-the-cockpit)

Comment: Voted to re-close: the duplicate should be the one re-opened.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: that asks about metaphorical “The cockpit of this fought was the Senate of the US”, whereas this asks about its evolution from cockfighting to aircraft.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think saying it is "metaphorical of cockfighting arenas" is necessarily a good answer. That seems pretty obvious, I wanted to know ***why*** and **how*** the word came to be used that way.

Comment: Had to look this up (again apparently, after 3.5y) after it being chauvinistically mentioned in *Captain Marvel*. Understanding how it went from a place where cocks fight and then all the way into aviation is in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293950/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-term-cockpit#comment658768_293951).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're correct, it was originally a pit where cockerels fought.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* says:

> a. A pit or enclosed area in which game-cocks are set to fight for sport; a place constructed for cock-fighting.

The first example is from 1587 in Thomas Churchyard's *The worthines of Wales*:

> The Mountaynes stands..In roundnesse such, as it a Cockpit were.

So the author is comparing the towering Welsh mountains to a cockpit. This non-direct use suggests the term must have been in common use for its analogous use to be understood here.

From this barbaric sport, the term was later applied to a place where a contest is fought (1612); to a theatre (1616; appropriately the first-known example is by playwright William Shakespeare); to a part of a warship where the junior officers quarters were, and where wounded were cared for during battle; and finally, more familiarly, to aeronautics (1914) and motor racing (1935).

Comment: Very interesting! Could you link the articles/sources you got the information from? I'd like to read more on it.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ Thanks! My source is the *Oxford English Dictionary*, here's a [link](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/35477?redirectedFrom=cockpit#eid) but unfortunately you'll need a subscription to access it (I use my library card, as my library subscribes). A much less-detailed source can be found [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cockpit&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: The transition from "fighting pit / theatre" to "ship compartment" seems like the biggest leap.  Are there theories as to how that happened?  My only guess is that if the cockpit of a ship was where the wounded were treated, there would be a lot of blood and guts in there, as there would in a cock-fighting pit.

Comment: @NateEldredge: They're all enclosed spaces. The theatre cockpit is aka the pit: the part of the theatre on the floor (and just look at Shakespeare's Globe).

Comment: @NateEldredge: ["The aft section of the lowest deck in a man-of-war, the cockpit was usually reserved for the quarters of the midshipmen and others, but was also used for the care of the wounded during engagements. There is also a fore cockpit usually reserved from he boatswain and carpenter."](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~HYPER/bb/bb_naut.html)

Comment: @NateEldredge: A confined space full of blood: ["At that time (the early eighteenth century), the term "cockpit" was in nautical use, denoting an area in the aft lower deck of a man-of-war where the wounded were taken. Like all lower-deck spaces, it was confined, humid, and badly lit. During a battle, it was also noisy, stinking and bloody. All this reminded people of a real cock-pit, hence the name."](http://cockpitcountry.com/cockpits.html)

Comment: IMO, this last comment is the real answer. It should be included in the answer, in full.

Comment: @Mazura Hear, hear! Which was also mentioned in Josh's deleted answer

Answer (score 9):

In the book *Fighting Cockpits 1914-2000: Design and Development of Military Aircraft Cockpits* (L. F. E. Coombs - 1999), it is mentioned that the origin of 'cockpit' as part of aviation terminology is uncertain. However, the book tries to explain the transition of the nautical term *cockpit* to aeronautics by saying that the designers and pilots who were also keen on sailing applied the term.

> It so happened that many of the pre 1914 flying machines provided no protection to the pilot from the elements. **Eventually the sides of the fuselage were raised and those designers and pilots who were also keen on sailing applied the nautical term 'cockpit' to their aircraft's control position.** In the sailing world 'cockpit' is specified as a depression in the deck for the tiller and helmsman. Another meaning comes from the bloody sport of cock fighting. In the Royal Air Force Communiques of 1918 we find 'cock-pit'. Aviation etymological research can lead to many origins.
>
> Bill Gunston's definition in Jane's Aerospace Dictionary is: 'Space occupied by pilot or other occupants, especially if open at the top. Preferably restricted to small aircraft in which the occupants cannot move from their seats'. The control position of the Wright Flyer of 1903 was not a cockpit within the accepted meaning of the word. As speed, altitude, manoeuvrability and anti-aircraft systems advanced decade by decade aircrew required greater and greater protection from the aerial environment and its hazards.

As an additional information, the website *http://www.wright-brothers.org/* applies the term *cockpit* to the *Wright Flyer III*:

> [image]
>
> A close-up view of the Flyer's cockpit from behind and to the left. The Flyer III was the last Wright aircraft on which the brothers lay prone to fly it. Note that the tubes that enclose the drive chain on the left side are crossed. The propellers rotate in opposite directions.